# RxJs channing, setting and reading external values

Tags: rxjs, observable, chaining

I'm new in rxjs world and I have to rewrite some code. So, I draft my ideas.

I have a request, which could fail and return an observable. I simulate that with the ob-variable and two map operations. Then, I try to catch an error. I need the result in my local variable *selected* and raise an event on *isChanged*. I call my function now via subscription. I don't need a result.

My question: Is one big pipe enough and can I use following approach for the work with my local variables?

```js
import { of, map, Observable, tap, Subject, throwError, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

let selected = 0;

const isChanged = new Subject<number>(); 

function myfunc(): Observable<boolean> {
  const ob = of(1,3,4,5,7);

  return ob.pipe(
    // simulates a http request
    map(v => v*2),
    // simulates a rare error condition
    map(v => {
     // if (v === 8) { throw `four`; }
      if (v === 10) { throw `ten`; }
      return v;
    }),
    // play with different failure situations
    catchError((e) => {
        if (e === `four`) {
          return of(4);
        }
        if (e === `ten`) {
          return EMPTY;
        }
        console.warn(e);
        return throwError(e);
      }
    ),
    // I need the result in a local variable
    // I need a information about success
    // I need the result not really
    map((res) => {
      selected = res;
      isChanged.next(res);
      return true;
    })
  );
}

console.log(`a: selected is ${selected}`);

isChanged.subscribe(v => 
  console.log(`b: isChanged received: ${v}, selected is ${selected}`));

console.log(`c: selected is ${selected}`);
// I have to call the function
myfunc().subscribe((b) => {  
  console.log(`d: selected is ${selected}`);
});
```

I create the world in Stackblitz too:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6fgggh?devtoolsheight=66&file=index.ts

I see results like expected. But I'm not sure if all ideas are the right way to solve all problems.

Thanks for you thought.

Comment: Yes, a tap is more appropriate when you want to do more computation on the input parameters and want to pass the same parameter without any modification to the next operator. We don't need to explicitly return it tap does it

Comment: So if I remove both taps and edit last map to `map((res) => {
      selected = res;
      isChanged.next(res);
      return true;
    })` it would be better (more lightweight)?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Unwanted 2 taps removed.

Comment: I wouldn't use throw error mechanism inside map function if the next step is catching it and projecting it to model. You could as well combine these two steps.